# How to move an object position in an Array of objects?

Tags: reactjs

I have an Array of objects in useState, I want to be able to move position up or down in the map loop.

```
  const data = [
    {id: 1, person: "John Doe"},
    {id: 2, person: "Jane Doe"},
    {id: 3, person: "Tom Bar"},
    {id: 4, person: "Jim Qux"},
  ]

  const [entries, setEntries] = useState(data)
```

I'm using this code I found online, it does move an object up if the the Array only contains two objects, if more than two it removes the rest.

```
  const moveUp = (index) => {
    if (index < 1 || index >= entries.length) {
      return;
    }

    setEntries(
      ([entries[index - 1], entries[index]] = [
        entries[index],
        entries[index - 1],
      ])
    );
  };
```

JSX:

```
{entries.map((item, index) => (
  <div key={item.id}>
    <h4>{item.person}</h4>

    <button onClick={() => moveUp(index)}>Move Up</button>
  </div>
))}
```

Comment: What's the question? What problem are you encountering? Errors? Unexpected behavior? What is the expected behavior?

Comment: The error is in the moveUp function, it only works as intended if the the Array only contains two objects, else it removes the rest of the objects within the Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't pass the assignment directly to `setEntries`. Instead, you can take the previous state, create a shallow copy, and then do the assignments with the copy.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function App() {
  const data = [
    { id: 1, person: "John Doe" },
    { id: 2, person: "Jane Doe" },
    { id: 3, person: "Tom Bar" },
    { id: 4, person: "Jim Qux" },
  ];

  const [entries, setEntries] = useState(data);

  const moveUp = (index) => {
    if (index < 1 || index >= entries.length) return;

    setEntries((entries) => {
      entries = [...entries];

      [entries[index - 1], entries[index]] = [
        entries[index],
        entries[index - 1],
      ];

      return entries;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {entries.map((item, index) => (
        <div key={item.id}>
          <h4>{item.person}</h4>

          <button onClick={() => moveUp(index)}>Move Up</button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If I may ask, if I copy the the moveUp function what will I need to change for moveDown function, I'm having problem making it work.

Comment: Change the assignments from `index - 1` to `index + 1`, I believe.

Comment: I did exactly that, but when I move the last one I get an error. Maybe something I need to change in the if statement?

Comment: Yeah I think it should be `if (index >= entries.length - 1) return;`.